# Class Constructor Confusion

Tags: c++, class

I have a class named client inside an header file and all the declaration and definition are inside the header. Now I need to separate this class in to source and header, but I am doubt about the constructor

```
class client{
  public:
    client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : stopped_(false),
    socket_(io_service),
    deadline_(io_service)
    {
          stream_buff = TPCircularBufferInit(stream_buff);
    }
 };
```

How can I implement this on source file.
like,

```
client::client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service){
? // what could be here
? // what could be here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code could also be written as:

```
class client{
    public:
        client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service);
};

client::client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service):
    stopped_(false),
    socket_(io_service),
    deadline_(io_service)
{
    stream_buff = TPCircularBufferInit(stream_buff);
}
```

Comment: But what is this stopped_(false),
    socket_(io_service),
    deadline_(io_service) is that function or variable.

Comment: It's a member initializer list. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: @Haris Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 3):

> *"How can I implement this on source file. like,"*

You use exactly the same syntax as you have used with the inline defintion:

```
class client{
  public:
    client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service);
 };

 client:client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : stopped_(false),
    socket_(io_service),
    deadline_(io_service)
    {
          stream_buff = TPCircularBufferInit(stream_buff);
    }
```